# Firefox bookmark manager with multiple instances

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, bookmarks

When you "show all bookmarks" in Firefox a "library" window pops up.  If you ever try to sort a huge amount of bookmarks you would appreciate having multiple "library" windows open.

Are there any bookmark managers that operate while Firefox is open and allow you to have multiple instances/windows as the "library" window?

Comment: Your question is not too clear. You want to drag and drop between multiple bookmark windows?

Comment: yes , (edited original post)

Answer (score 2):

You can open this chrome URL in new tabs to have multiple instances of the Library open:

chrome://browser/content/places/places.xul

and can view the tabs side-by-side with the [Tile Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tile-tabs/) extension.

Comment: This is now: http://chrome//browser/content/places/bookmarksSidebar.xhtml (FF 94)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using a combination of one or all of:

1. [Bookmark search plus 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/bookmark-search-plus-2/)
2. The built-in bookmark manager <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
3. The built-in [bookmarks sidebar](http://chrome://browser/content/places/bookmarksSidebar.xhtml)

Advice taken from [this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1284813) on Mozilla/Firefox support and working on Firefox 94.01.

I can see that a moved bookmark in one of the above bookmark tools shows as being moved in the others. But you may want to exercise caution as I'm not certain this is a fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

Having the Bookmarks Sidebar and the Manage Bookmarks facilities open at the same time is the only way I've found to more easily move bookmarks around. I've posted to user groups and looked at all the addons and this seems to be the answer.

Some things like selecting multiple bookmarks work differently in the sidebar versus the Manage Bookmarks library. Just a few differences I've had to adjust my approach for, are (BTW I've looked many times but haven't found any article that addresses what the differences are or explain *why* there are differences):

Manage Bookmarks - can select multiple folders or bookmarks.
Sidebar - can only select one folder or bookmark.
Manage Bookmarks - can delete folders or bookmarks with the delete key.
Sidebar - have to right-click and use the dropdown menu.
Manage Bookmarks - does not show separators.
Sidebar - separators are visible.

I almost always use Manage Bookmarks as the "move from" list bc I can select multiples. The Sidebar is also clumsy when dragging bookmarks from one folder to another.